# Oracle Explain Plan via Sqlplus but for Multiple Queries from One Execution?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm curious how would a structure look like from SQL Plus perspective mixed with bash magic, so the idea is to be able to parse x amount of .sql files with queries in them, how would this look like, for a single file it would be :

```
-- generate the explain plan
EXPLAIN PLAN SET statement_id = 'example_plan1' 
FOR
  select * from dbms.database1_1 where numberline like '%4214%';

-- actually display the results
select plan_table_output 
  from table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table',null,'typical'));
```

But I'm unsure how it would look like from perspective of multi parse:

Example I upload 10-13 SQL's and I want all of them parsed via xplain and return the info either in one file or one for each, I guess one total result is more simple and easier to create.

Comment: Perform `explain plan` in a loop using differnt `statement_id`'s. For reporting use the `statement_id` as an explicite parameter - such as `from table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table','example_plan_13,'typical'))`

Comment: Hmm, well, I'm also spooling the output, it would be simple to loop set amount of queries from folder but the second select from dbms plan kind of screw it over, the idea is to also prevent user from executing queries, so lets say what ever user uploads, it gets taken as sql file and used as @file.sql , so example

Comment: `spool /Output1/output-2/&&v_spool
set lines 12345 pages 12345;
EXPLAIN PLAN SET statement_id = 'example_plan1' FOR
@test.sql
select plan_table_output
  from table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table',null,'typical'));
EXPLAIN PLAN SET statement_id = 'example_plan2' FOR
@test2.sql
select plan_table_output
  from table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table',null,'typical'));
SET TIMING OFF
spool off
EXIT
EOF`